# Unselecting a range

Tags: excel, vba, select, range

I am currently copying and pasting a range. The problem I am having is that once the macro has run I am left with the range still selected. How do I remove the green rectangle..."deselect"?? The code I am using is:

```
        For x = 0 To 10
        Range("O" & (34 - x) & ": V" & (34 - x)).Copy
        NextRow = ("O" & (35 - x) & ": V" & (35 - x))
        Range(NextRow).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
        Next x
```

I have tried:

```
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I would really appreciate some help!
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: record a macro doing what you want save the macro, view the source. copy what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution - avoid the use of `Select` and `Copy` or `Paste` in the first place...

```
For x = 0 To 10    
    NextRow = ("O" & (35 - x) & ": V" & (35 - x))
    Range(NextRow).Value = Range("O" & (34 - x) & ": V" & (34 - x)).Value
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the line at the beginning of your macro:

```
Set objInitSel = ActiveSheet.Selection
```

And at the end of the macro:

```
objInitSel.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave already mentioned, you're best avoiding the use of the `.Select` property.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and it's answers gives a good explanation of how to avoid using `select` and the reasons behind why you should avoid using `select`.

Primarily: inefficiency and causation of errors.

The 2 main alternatives to using select is:

1. Directly use the `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` methods with a range (reducing four lines of code into one):

`Range("O" & (34 - x) & ": V" & (34 - x)).copy Range("O" & (35 - x) & ": V" & (35 - x))`

2. Assign the values of one range to another range:

`Range("O" & (35 - x) & ": V" & (35 - x)) = Range("O" & (34 - x) & ": V" & (34 - x))`